# Magento 2.4.3 Remove products from cart

Tags: magento2, cart

The customer has 500+ items in their cart. Items has not removed when click "Remove All" button.

The below code in resolve function is used to remove cart items

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ArgumentsProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\GetCartForUser;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId;

/**
 * Class for remove items from cart
 */
class RemoveItemsFromCart implements ResolverInterface {
    /**
     * @var GetCartForUser
     */
    private $getCartForUser;

    /**
     * @var CartItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $cartItemRepository;

    /**
     * @var MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId
     */
    private $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId;

    /**
     * @var ArgumentsProcessorInterface
     */
    private $argsSelection;

    /**
     * @param GetCartForUser $getCartForUser
     * @param CartItemRepositoryInterface $cartItemRepository
     * @param MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId
     * @param ArgumentsProcessorInterface $argsSelection
     */
    public function __construct(
        GetCartForUser $getCartForUser,
        CartItemRepositoryInterface $cartItemRepository,
        MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId,
        ArgumentsProcessorInterface $argsSelection
    ) {
        $this->getCartForUser = $getCartForUser;
        $this->cartItemRepository = $cartItemRepository;
        $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId = $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId;
        $this->argsSelection = $argsSelection;
    }

    /**
     * Remove multiple items from cart
     */
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null) {
        $processedArgs = $this->argsSelection->process($info->fieldName, $args);
        if (empty($processedArgs['input']['cart_id'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Required parameter "cart_id" is missing.'));
        }
        $maskedCartId = $processedArgs['input']['cart_id'];
        try {
            $cartId = $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId->execute($maskedCartId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(
                __('Could not find a cart with ID "%masked_cart_id"', ['masked_cart_id' => $maskedCartId])
            );
        }
        if (empty($processedArgs['input']['cart_items']["item_id"])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Required parameter "cart_item_id" is missing.'));
        }
        $items = $processedArgs['input']['cart_items']["item_id"];
        $storeId = (int) $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            foreach ($items as $item){
                $this->cartItemRepository->deleteById($cartId, $item);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(__('The cart doesn\'t contain the item'));
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__($e->getMessage()), $e);
        }
        $cart = $this->getCartForUser->execute($maskedCartId, $context->getUserId(), $storeId);
        return [
            'cart' => [
                'model' => $cart,
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me the file path ?

Comment: @Himanshu its a custom code & file

Comment: i have added full code

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Can you please share the grapQL here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete/remove the quote instead of just removing all items from cart.

```
    <?php
    declare (strict_types = 1);
    
    namespace Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Model\Resolver;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ArgumentsProcessorInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
    use Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\GetCartForUser;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
    
    /**
     * Class for remove items from cart
     */
    class RemoveItemsFromCart implements ResolverInterface {
        /**
         * @var GetCartForUser
         */
        private $getCartForUser;
    
        /**
         * @var CartItemRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $cartItemRepository;
    
        /**
         * @var MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId
         */
        private $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId;
    
        /**
         * @var ArgumentsProcessorInterface
         */
        private $argsSelection;
    
        /**
         * @var CartRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $quoteRepository;
    
        /**
         * @param GetCartForUser $getCartForUser
         * @param CartItemRepositoryInterface $cartItemRepository
         * @param MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId
         * @param ArgumentsProcessorInterface $argsSelection
         * @param CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
         */
        public function __construct(
            GetCartForUser $getCartForUser,
            CartItemRepositoryInterface $cartItemRepository,
            MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteId $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId,
            ArgumentsProcessorInterface $argsSelection,
            CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
        ) {
            $this->getCartForUser = $getCartForUser;
            $this->cartItemRepository = $cartItemRepository;
            $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId = $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId;
            $this->argsSelection = $argsSelection;
            $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        }
    
        /**
         * Remove multiple items from cart
         */
        public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null) {
            $processedArgs = $this->argsSelection->process($info->fieldName, $args);
            if (empty($processedArgs['input']['cart_id'])) {
                throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Required parameter "cart_id" is missing.'));
            }
            $maskedCartId = $processedArgs['input']['cart_id'];
            try {
                $cartId = $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId->execute($maskedCartId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
                throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(
                    __('Could not find a cart with ID "%masked_cart_id"', ['masked_cart_id' => $maskedCartId])
                );
            }
            $storeId = (int) $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                if($cartId){
                    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
                    $quote->delete();
                }
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                throw new GraphQlNoSuchEntityException(
                    __('Unable to remove item')
                );
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@devhs **$cartId** definition is missing from your code.

Refer the below code from core:

/vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/RemoveItemFromCart.php

inside resolve() method:

```
$cart = $this->getCartForUser->execute($maskedCartId, $context->getUserId(), $storeId);

$this->cartItemRepository->deleteById((int)$cart->getId(), $itemId);
```

Comment: i have added full code in question & cart is already passed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. This is the core function where we can use to clear the customers' cart.

```
protected $cart;

 
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

/**
     * Empty customer's shopping cart
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _emptyShoppingCart()
    {
        try {
            $this->cart->truncate()->save();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $exception) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($exception->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($exception, __('We can\'t update the shopping cart.'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will delete the cart as well or just the products in cart ?

Comment: It will delete quote items i.e., cart items will clear.

Comment: The cart doesn't contain the item
This error i am facing,
i have cross checked cart item do exist still error.

Comment: Do i need to first load the cart using the id then ->truncate()->save(); ?

I am not how to use             $this->cart->truncate()->save();
in the code i have added in question ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please try now.

Comment: This code will work in resolver as well ?

Comment: Also This "truncate" will just mark all quote items as deleted (empty shopping cart) not actually remove item from "quote" in quote table.

Comment: @devhs Have you tried? we have implemented this to one of customer and working. When call this function the customer cart items are cleared/removed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments & answer, yes i have tried it seems working though
issue is it does not clear the "items_count" & "items_qty" for quote id in "quote" table.

Comment: @devhs, It should work, double check after call this function you should reload the page to effect the changes. It will work same as minicart/updateAll cart items update.

Comment: Thanks let me check with code & how $this->cart gets the cart object ?
with out passing cart id ?

Comment: I have tested it its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130052/discussion-between-bojjaiah-and-devhs).