# Magento 2 : remove all products from cart

Tags: magento2, cart

I am using Magento 2.4.3 EE

Is there any way we can remove all products from the cart using the cart id?

I have checked on using "removeItem" & "deleteItem" but it needs to loop the cart items which is not suitable when the cart has more than 400+ products.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/NagendraKodi/magento-2-clear-cart

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::removeAllItems()`

Answer (score 0):

By cart id I assume you mean quote_id? you can just use some SQL if this is a one off fix :

```
delete FROM `quote_item` WHERE quote_id = X
```

Comment: This is not the recommended method.
Also i meant initiating cart object using quote id & delete all the cart items exist in it.

Comment: Understood, but im assuming you're asking because of this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347432/magento-2-4-3-remove-products-from-cart
 if the recommended method was perfectly written code then the Remove all button should be able to handle this task.  Since it can't best to look around.

Comment: not sure about it.